# Is there an easy way to check (in elisp) if only one character has changed in a buffer before saving it?

Tags: saving

I have a typing problem in Emacs under WSL.  Sometimes it misses my typing ^x as in ^xp and ^xo (prev and next window in my bindings) and I get a stray p or o character in the buffer I want to leave (and I often don't notice it).  But it I save all buffers (like I do when typing compile/make), those stray characters can get written out.  There is usually just one of them.

So, I want to hack my save-buffer to check if the modification is just one character before saving and ask for comfirmation if it is.  Something like:

```
(defun my-save-buffer () 
  (interactive)
  (when (or (not (only-one-char-changed))
          (y-or-n-p "changed only one character, really save?")
          ) ; or
     (save-buffer)
     ) ; when
   )
```

The question is how to ask "only-one-char-changed" relatively efficiently?  E.g. something I can ask the undo information about.

Comment: Put your code on `before-save-hook` (once you have the code to check what you want and prompt about it).

Comment: Please do not post the same question to both StackOverflow and SE.emacs. Please choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: Sorry, had forgotten about this site when I posted the first copy.